# SQL Alchemy Unique index cannot be created- giving error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

the index gives an error message

```
Index('unique-example', example.c.col1, example.c.col2, unique=True)
```

Why is this the case?

This is my class

```
class ExampleClass(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'example'
   __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}, (Index('unique-example', col1, col2, unique=True))

   index = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, nullable=False)
   col1 = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
   col2  = Column(String, nullable=True)
   col3  = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a dictionary with keyword arguments should be the last argument in the `__table_args__`, see [Table Configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration)

```
__table_args__ = (Index('unique-example', 'col1', 'col2', unique=True)), {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
```